# Using Linq to get records that have specific foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying get all records from a table that have a specific foreign key but I'm struggling to get linq to return anything useful.

**Post Model**

```
public class Post
{
    //... irrelevant properties
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId;
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

**my dbo.Posts table**

[image]

**What I've tried**

I've tried several variations of the following:

```
//id = 7

using (UnitOfWork uwork = new UnitOfWork())
{
    var post = uwork.PostRepository.GetAll().Where(c => c.CategoryId == id);

}
```

This only returns "Non-Public members", which doesn't contain anything useful.

[image]

### Question

How could I modify my linq query to return all posts that have a specific Foreign Key id?

---

*updates*

### [here's my repository](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/610c09e67b5c1c4343f4)

Comment: What does the repository do on `GetAll`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are basically looking at `DbQuery<T>` object, which is an implementation of `IQueryable<T>`. Basically LINQ did not make a query yet, because no one asked it for data. So instead it collects all info about the query in an object, to execute it later when needed.

To force it to give you the actual data, simply do `ToList`, or iterate over posts, or anything:

```
var post = uwork.PostRepository.GetAll().Where(c => c.CategoryId == id).ToList();
```

Just make sure to do so *before* you expose the db context object.

Comment: This threw an error: *The specified type member 'CategoryId' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.*

Comment: Well, that's now entire different story. Something is wrong with your ORM mapping. Looks like you have Category_Id in your table, and CategoryId in the object - that might be an issue. But the key thing is that linq did execute the query now

Comment: Agreed, looks like I need to update my model. thank you and I'll accept this as the answer